# Jmeter - Trigger if condition via Command line value

Tags: jmeter

Using JMeter I would like to execute a script where the script is entering into specific condition based on the property provided via windows CMD execution. My script looks like:

[image]

and execution is done via CMD as:

```
jmeter -n -t C:\Users\test\Documents\api.jmx -Jusers=1
```

How can I enter into just single specific If controller, based on the value provided on the runtime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should rather go for a single [Switch Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Switch_Controller) instead of 3 If Controllers and use [__P() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__P) to read the value from the command line:

```
${__P(scenario,)}
```

[image]

This way if you execute JMeter as:

```
jmeter -Jscenario=A -Jusers=1 -n -t C:\Users\test\Documents\api.jmx
```

it will run Sampler (or a [Logic Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#logic_controllers)) named `A`, similarly for `B` and `C`

You may also find [Running JMeter Samplers with Defined Percentage Probability](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/running-jmeter-samplers-defined-percentage-probability) article useful.

Answer (score 0):

Add check to users parameter for each If, in your case:

```
${__groovy(props.get("users")=="1")}
```

> Checking this and using __jexl3 or __groovy function in Condition is advised for performances